# how to get random emission colours on a joined mesh which are not adjacent

Tags: node-editor, emission

I'm following along this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aHgTjruqvk

My mesh consists of duplicated squares which I joined and made them into on object.
is it possible for each rectangle to have its own separate color, as I slide the color ramp node?

[image]
[image]